# Any other official one-stop source for android development guidelines apart from developer site?

Tags: android, android-framework

well , i am into android development since 4 months now (yes a newbie), but after developing few apps, and getting to play around the codes, there are always doubts in my mind like:

- Was that the perfect way to do it?
- Is there something i can add?
- How can i improve my code/ design?

And Android Documentation do help a lot, but is it the only trustworthy source? Is there something similar to this like one place to clear all android concepts but in a much more  clearer way?
And eventually at times, there is a need for source of guidelines or rules for beginner android developers, wherein one can always cross check whether they are on the right track

Yes, knowledge do comes with experience and implementing all the features of android framework seems improbable , and by the time i complete that,
there will be a new Android API announced/ launched

Is there any source that can help the beginners with questions like:

- When to use what?
- How to efficiently use it?
- What is better? this or that?

Also guidelines such as :

- UI design
- best practices
- Do's and Dont's
- Top 50 things to remember
  which can go a long way in helping novices to clear conceptual/ fundamental doubts

Just wanted to know if anyone knows if something like this exists?  because all i do is search google, and try to read /understand what seems useful, So never really get to know if its a source worth to be trusted  .....
thanks everyone who can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are my 4 best suggestions:

- [The Developer Guide (official from Android.com)](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html)
- [Android Video Talks from Google I/O and others](http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html)
- [Android Development Books](http://commonsware.com/Android/) (40dollas for an year subscription) I'm reading these books atm.
- New and official [Android Training Site](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html)

I think this is all you need :)